# Question on $\pi$-systems

Tags: probability-theory

I understand that when it comes to two probability spaces, we can show that if their measures agree on $\pi$-systems generating the same $\sigma$-algebra, then the spaces agree on the entire space. A $\pi$-system is a family of subsets of our space that is closed under finite intersections. However, what I note is that

(i) If I have some subset $E \subseteq \Omega$ for which I know $\mu(E)$, then I have by default that $\mu(\Omega \setminus E) = 1 - \mu(E)$,

(ii) If I know the measures $\mu(E_{i})$ for some countable set of disjoint sets $\{ E_{i} : i \in I \}$, then I can get $\mu(\cup_{i \in I} E_{i}) = \sum_{i \in I}E_{i}$.

For example, let $\Omega = \{1, 2, 3 \}$, $\mathcal{F} = 2^{\Omega}$, and $\mu( \{ 1 \}) = \mu ( \{ 2 \} = \frac{1}{3}$. Then I can construct the whole probability space by

\begin{align*}
\mu( \{1, 2, 3 \} ) & = 1 & (\textrm{definition of probability space}) \\
\mu(\emptyset) & = 0 & (\textrm{definition of meausre}) \\
\mu( \{1 \}) & = \frac{1}{3} \\
\mu(\{2 \} & = \frac{1}{3} \\
\mu( \{ 1, 2 \} ) & = \frac{2}{3} & ( \{1, 2\} = \{1 \} \cup \{2 \}) \\
\mu( \{3 \}) & = \frac{1}{3} & (\{ 3 \} = \Omega \setminus \{1, 2 \} \\
\mu( \{1, 3 \} & = \frac{2}{3} & ( \{1, 3 \} = \Omega \setminus \{ 2 \}) \\
\mu( \{2, 3 \} & = \frac{2}{3} & ( \{2, 3 \} = \Omega \setminus \{1 \}
\end{align*}

However, all I properly used was the measures for $\{1 \}, \{2 \}$, and the assumption I was dealing in a probability space. However, $\{ \{1 \}, \{2 \} \}$ is not remotely a $\pi$-system.

This leads me to wonder: Is there a weaker class of families of subsets which can be used to generate a probability space, and thus establish equivalency of probability spaces? Or is this just something that comes up in finite probability spaces?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Well, $\{\{1\},\{2\}\}\cup\{\emptyset\}$ is indeed a $\pi$-system that generates the whole $\sigma$-algebra. So I guess you could "generalise" the theorem on $\pi$-systems by saying that if $\mathcal{A}\cup\{\emptyset\}$ is a $\pi$-system generating the whole $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ then any probability measure is uniquely determined on $\mathcal{A}$. It's a pretty trivial corollary though.

I imagine the answer to "Is there a weaker class of families of subsets..." is no. At the most basic level, if $A,B\in\mathcal{F}$ are not disjoint, then I cannot see how we can determine $\mu(A\cap B)$ given only $\mu(A)$ and $\mu(B)$. So you would need some kind of intersection property.

Comment: What about if you could make $A \cap B$ as a union of other elements. I guess I'm interested in when you have niceties in terms of unions instead of intersections.

Comment: It would have to be a disjoint union. I'm not saying it's impossible, but I think if we want "interesting" examples we would probably be after families which are closed with respect to some operation. The difficulty in extending a measure defined on some generating subset is always in the intersections.